# How to save the contents of an environment in a different file

Tags: macros

I have 1 tex file for example `A.tex` has the following content:

```
\begin{Solution}{1}
D
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{2}
D
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{3}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{4}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{5}
C
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{6}
C
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{7}
A
\end{Solution}
```

From this `A.tex` file I want to extract a tex file called `B.tex` whose content is: DDABCCA (i.e. only content in the Solution environment)
I hope everyone helps!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. I hope everyone helps as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here I provide two approaches:
 - an `xparse` approach which requires `xparse` 2019-03-05 or newer and
 - an `environ` approach

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
%% xparse approach, require xparse 2019-03-05 or newer
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\NewDocumentEnvironment{Solution}{m +b}
%  {\g@addto@macro\solution@body@acc{#2}}
%  {}
%% end of xparse approach

%% environ approach
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Solution}[1]{%
  \xdef\solution@body@acc{\solution@body@acc\BODY}%
}
%% end of environ approach

% accumulation of "Solution" body
\def\solution@body@acc{}

% read A.tex, the "Solution" body is accumulated in \solution@body@acc
\input{A}

% write to B.tex
\newwrite\outputB
\immediate\openout\outputB B.tex
\immediate\write\outputB{\solution@body@acc}
\immediate\closeout\outputB
\makeatother


\begin{document}
pass
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I recompile the following error, hope you review it for me: ! LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment Solution'.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.

Comment: @HoacthanTran The `b` argument type requires `xparse` 2019-03-05 or newer. I have added a `environ` approach which should work on older latex distributions.

Comment: Thank you for the successful compilation. Wish you good health and happiness.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\Solution` environment:

```
\def\solutions{}
\def\Solution#1#2 #3 #4\end#5{\end{Solution}\edef\solutions{\solutions#3}}
```

Then you can read the file `A.tex`. The result is in the `\solutions` macro:

```
Solutions are: \solutions.
```